# MP3 audio not working in firefox browser / android firefox browser

Tags: html, audio, mp3

I am using Html5 audio tag in my site and referring only mp3 audio format(not ogg), its working fine in firefox browser from a test server but when same code deployed on live site then its not playing the audio in firefox browser.

```
<audio controls>  
<source src="planetarian.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Please help me to find out the root why same code is play from a server but on live its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 21+ started to support the MP3 files, please check your mime type on server whether MP3 is added there or not.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem.once I make it mp3 file as 64kbps bit rate,It's working for me.please check your audio bit rate.